# Highlight All fields Nest ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

everybody

I'm working with Nest driver of elasticsearch for c#. In my project I don't have any document mapping so, if I want to highlight matching fields I should use this Json part in my query which highlights all fields:

```
"highlight":{
    "fields":{
      "*":{}
    }
  }
```

but I want to do it with nest. I use this code:

```
 client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
       .Index('my index name')
       .Type('my doc type name')
       .From(page*PageSize)
       .Size(PageSize)
       .Query(q => q
              .QueryString(qs => qs.Query('my query')))
       .Highlight(h => h
              .OnFields(f => f
                    .OnAll()
                    .PreTags("<b style='color:black'>")
                    .PostTags("</b>")
       )));
```

and it is not working for me, returned result contains hits, but doesn't contain any highlight :(

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are looking for

```
client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
   .Index('my index name')
   .Type('my doc type name')
   .From(page*PageSize)
   .Size(PageSize)
   .Query(q => q
          .QueryString(qs => qs.Query('my query')))
   .Highlight(h => h
          .OnFields(f => f
                .OnField("*")
                .PreTags("<b style='color:black'>")
                .PostTags("</b>")
   )));
```

because `.OnAll()` means `.OnField("_all")`.

[Take a look](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Nest/DSL/Search/HighlightFieldDescriptor.cs#L128-131)

UPDATE: object initializer syntax(NEST 5.x)

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    Query = ..
    Highlight = new Highlight
    {
        PostTags = new[] {"<a>"},
        PreTags = new[] {"</a>"},
        Fields = new FluentDictionary<Field, IHighlightField>().Add("*", new HighlightField())
    }
};
```

Comment: how will you do that with object initializer method?

Comment: awsome. thanks this is working but quick question, this returns for almost all  fields. for example, I have nameEN, nameDE in my index but in my query I request only nameEN, I see nameDE in the hightlights as well. is it not depending on actual query or it is interpreted as a separate query?